# Disable wireless light?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-registry, network-adapter

Is there any way (program, registry key, etc.) that I could disable the little light that turns on whenever WiFi is enabled? I would still like to have WiFi enabled, it's just that I want the light to be off.

If it helps I have a Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card.

Comment: probably a dell studio, right?

Comment: you can do this but you would need to modify the bios firmware to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Duct tape.

Other than that, theres no real way to turn it off.

Comment: Or electrical tape!

Comment: Or even worse - crack open the case and desolder the LED... (trust me, coming up with these ideas is way easier than actually implementing them)

Comment: There had to be some way. It's tied by software to the wireless card's state, so shouldn't it be possible to access it through software in some manner?

Comment: The software? You mean the closed source windows drivers?

Comment: Blu Tac / Stick Tack is useful to block the light and not have to try and peel off a sticky tape.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7 my toggle switch doesn't actually do anything except turn the light on and off, it doesn't actually turn the wireless ON.

To turn it on manually you have to enter the Control Panel, Device manager -> Network Adapters -> *Your wireless card* -> Properties -> Advanced -> "Link State" or something like that (I'm not on my laptop now) and just set that to true

So by doing that *I* can have wireless without the light by doing it manually like that. It might not work for you though, just something to try if nothing else works :D

Comment: I'm using xp, but I'll see if it works.

Comment: Hm... I can't seem to find a link state option per say. Still looking though.

Answer (score 1):

The following link's instructions worked on my Dell E4300. You should find a similar setting for your WiFi card in the same place:

["How to disable indicator lights through registry tweaks"](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-and-U-series-Laptops/How-to-disable-indicator-lights-through-registry-tweaks/ta-p/263165)